# PostgreSQL case sensitive

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to configure postgres to ignore case sensitivity by default?

When I do this query I get 0 rows returned

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'Email@email.com';
```

But when I do this I get 1 row returned

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'email@email.com';
```

Can I set it to default ignore case sensitivity? so Email = email?

Comment: no. only `SELECT * FROM users WHERE lower(email) = lower('Email@email.com');`

Comment: You can use `ILIKE`